# redis lock acquiring not working - stays running and never acquires

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis, locking, aioredis

this is my code:

```
pool = aioredis.ConnectionPool.from_url("redis://localhost:6379")
redis = await aioredis.Redis(connection_pool=pool, ssl=False, ssl_cert_reqs="None")

async with redis.lock("hello_lock") as lock:
    print("hello")
    await redis.hset("hello", "1", "2")
```

the Context Manager never gets entered and it seems like the lock is not being acquired at all. The program stays running/stuck on this line:
`async with redis.lock("hello_lock") as lock:`

Acquiring the lock should be a very quick thing so i'm confused whats happening here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your bug seem to be in the Redis server configuration, if you have other clients connected to Redis and they are executing long-running commands, the lock acquisition could be blocked

Comment: my redis server is local and im testing with it. Im 100% sure there are no other clients connected

Comment: @Saxtheowl whats weird is that locking works with other libraries such as aioredlock. But not with aioredis built-in locking

Comment: I made an answer with a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem with the Redis lock implementation, try the following commands to manually acquire and release a lock:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> SET my_lock "1" NX
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> GET my_lock
"1"
```

If that still dont work try another method of lock like RedLock or RLock